# three-state Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

a male and a female go to a $2$-table restaurant on the same day.
each day the male sits at one or the other of the $2$ tables, starting at the table $1$, with a Markov chain transition matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0.3 & 0.7\\
 0.7 & 0.3\end{bmatrix}$$
similarly the female sits at one or the other of the $2$ tables, starting at the table $2$, with a Markov chain transition matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0.4 & 0.6\\
 0.6 & 0.4\end{bmatrix}$$
assume that $2$ chains are independent.

a. model this situation with a three-state Markov chain and transition matrix.

b. find the probability that the male sits at table $1$ and the female sits at table $2$ on day $2,3$ and $4$.

c. if $N$ is the number of days that the male and the female sit the same table, then how can we describe the random variable $N$?

I'm new to markov chain and each time I work out part (a), I get a different answer. Can someone help?

Comment: Show (at least one of) your answers to part (a).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The possible states for the markov chain are: {Both sit together, Male sites at Table $1$ and Female at Table $2$, Male sits at Table $2$ and Female at Table $1$}.

Comment: Why should this yield a Markov chain?

Comment: Because the probability of transition to a state is dependent on only the previous state and not on the entire history of the chain.

Comment: This is not true at the state (Both sit together). The transition to (Male at table 1 and Female at table 2) depends on whether Male and Female are both at table 1 or both at table 2. Hence, unless I am missing a miracle somewhere, the lumped process is not Markov.

Comment: Both at table 1 or both at table 2 is included in the state "both sit together".

Comment: Sure, and so what? Please read my previous comment.

Comment: I re-read your previous comment and fail to see how my last comment is irrelevant.

Comment: There are general conditions for the process obtained by lumping together some states of a Markov process to be itself Markov. These are not met here hence a priori the process you suggest is not Markov. Note however that the lumped process with the two states "At the same table" and "Not at the same table", is Markov (but only on two states).